# How can I use a python variable as an input / output for a C function using Cython?

Tags: python, c, cython

So I have a C implementation of a hashmap where I can store heterogeneous data. The interface for it looks something like this:

```c
error_e put(const char* key, const type_e type, const void* data);

error_e get(const char* key, const type_e type, void* data);
```

Where `error_e` is an enum defining all the various errors I can receive and `type_e` is an enum defining all the various types of data I can store.
Now I want to create a python wrapper for this using cython. This is what I have so far in my `hashmap.pyx`:

```
cdef extern from "hashmap.h":
    cdef enum error_e:
      # some enum values...

    cdef enum type_e:
        type_empty  = 0,
        type_int32  = 1,
        type_float  = 2,
        type_string = 3

    error_e put(const char* key, const type_e type, const void* value)
    error_e get(const char* key, const type_e type, void* value)

class Hashmap:
    def __init__(self):
        self.type_dict = {
            int: type_int32,
            float: type_float,
            str: type_string
        }

    def put(self, key, value):
        if not type(value) in self.type_dict:
            return unknown_type

        # Not sure what to do here?

        return put(key.encode('utf-8'), self.type_dict[type(value)], &value) # Obviously doesn't work

    def get(self, key, val_type):
        if not val_type in self.type_dict:
            return unknown_type

        # Also not really sure what to do here

        res = get(key.encode('utf-8'), self.type_dict[val_type], # How can I get data out of here?)
        return (res, data)
```

I'm having problems with getting a void pointer from the value that should be written / read from the hashmap from a python object. I've tried to use if else statements for the different types and converting the input to them, but I can't seem to be able to then get a pointer to the correct thing.

So this leads me to my questions:
1) How could I use the value of a python variable as an input to a C function that takes a `void*`?
2) How could I get data out of a C function and into a python variable if the function takes a `void*`?

edit 1:

Some additional information about how the C functions are supposed to be used:
The `void*` supplied to them is a pointer to a C object with the value you want to store / get. The type of the value is supplied using the `type` parameter. Currently only ints, floats and strings are supported.
I don't want to store python objects in the hashmap, nor do I want the C code to have any reference to python, since I want to store values using python, save the hashmap and then retrieve and use them using C.

edit 2:

Here's a small example of how you could add values to the hashmap in C:

```
int32_t some_int = 5;
put("int_key", type_int32, &some_int);

float some_float = 3.1416;
put("pi", type_float, &some_float);

char* some_string = "some text you want to store";
put("text", type_string, some_string);
```

And here how you'd get values out of the same one:

```
int32_t returned_int;
get("int_key", type_int32, &returned_int);

float returned_float;
get("pi", type_float, &returned_float);

char returned_string[30];
get("text", type_string, returned_string);
```

When storing or retrieving something from the hashmap, it will always either copy your data into its internal storage or copy the data from the storage to the supplied "buffer" location.

Comment: If you don't think the linked question answers what you're asking then ping me and let me know. It really isn't obvious how you're supposed to get data out of the function because you don't show what it actually does!

Comment: Oh yeah, I realize now that it's not obvious how the C functions are supposed to be used. The gist of it is, that you enter data into and get data out of the hashmap using C datatypes and not python types. This means you supply the `put(...)` and `get(...)` functions with a `void*` to a C object with the value type being passed using the type parameter. I'll edit the question to explain this a bit more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing we *still* don't know if how this library expects to be used from C. The Cython implementation will almost certainly look a lot like the C implementation and without that it's largely just a guess.

However, if I were doing this in C I think the structure I'd be using us a "Union" - you can define it in Cython as:

```
cdef union DataType:
    int32_t as_int
    float as_float
    char* as_string
```

`put` would then look something like:

```
cdef DataType data
if isinstance(value, int):
    data.as_int = value
# etc.
return put(key.encode('utf-8'), self.type_dict[type(value)], <void*>(&data)) # Obviously doesn't work
```

`get` is kind of the inverse:

```
cdef DataType data
res = get(key.encode('utf-8'), self.type_dict[val_type], <void*>(&data))

if something_to_do_with_val_type is int:
    out = data.as_int
# etc.
```

---

Obviously the C string needs some extra thought because (as ever) something needs to own the memory. You really run the risk of ending up with a pointer to the internals of a Python object that no longer exists. I don't have enough information to even make an intelligent guess as to how you should handle that.

Comment: I really like the idea of the union. That definitely makes it quite nice. I might be able to make the interface of the hashmap more uniform, to not need a special case for the C string (meaning changing it so that you can supply a char** instead of having to supply a char*), but the owning of the memory is still something I worry about. Do you have any ideas there? Instead of just having a massive buffer in the union.

Comment: There isn't an obvious good answer. In C a `const char* x = "some literal"` defined as a constant will keep existing indefinitely, but that doesn't really apply to points to Python objects. You could just use a limited range of C constants and not Python objects. Or you could make the user responsible for both `malloc` and `free`